# How to create an array with its first list being ['0','1','2',...] etc up to 8? (as strings, not integers)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Making a treasure hunt game and for the board, I would like numbers along the top and side for coordinates of a grid, the top line will be the numbers 0-8 in a list. Here's my code:

```
board=[]
board.append([])
for i in range(9):
    i2=str(i)
    board[i].append(i2)
```

Although when i run it I get the error:

```
board[i].append(i2)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Here is a list with the first element as a space, and then the first nine digits `[' ', *map(str, range(9))]` Should work on 3.5+.  Or for just the numbers `[str(i) for i in range(9)]`

Comment: @MooingRawr actually it'd go out of range at `i=1` since indexing starts at 0, @LMSystem815 if you append a single sublist then you only have a single sublist, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk),

```
board = [[str(i) for i in range(9)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to input into board[1] (when the loop goes for the second time) python crashes since  that sub-list doesn't exist replace board[i] with board[0]:

```
board=[]
board.append([])
for i in range(9):
    i2=str(i)
    board[0].append(i2)
```